# Camera doesnt rotate x axis using javafx

Tags: java, javafx, rotation

ive been using javafx recently and while i was doing so ive caught a problem in my code but spending a lot of time on it (mostly googling it) i cannot find the solution to my problem.

The problem happens when i try to rotate the camera using the x axis but instead of doing what i was wanting to happen instead it rotates around (0,0,0). Im not sure if it does rotate around (0,0,0) but that was the solution i could figure out. My camera starts staring at a cube but when tun left (adds 2 to the x axis) and the box goes a big circle. When turning right the box moves the other way around the circle. When applying the axis to the box, the box goes around fine.

My code is a bit messy but what i tried is to get the movement of turning and the box should go left if i turn right and right if i turn left as if in real life how it works.

```
public class javafx extends Application {
    int ze = 0;
    int ye = 0;
    int xe = 0;

        PerspectiveCamera cam = new PerspectiveCamera();
//the rotation angles//
 Rotate rx = new Rotate();

        { rx.setAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS); }
        Rotate ry = new Rotate();
        { ry.setAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS); }
        Rotate rz = new Rotate();
        { rz.setAxis(Rotate.Z_AXIS); }
  

        int xt = 0;
        int yt = 0;
        int one;
        int two;
        boolean flip = false;
    public static void addRotate(Node node, Point3D rotationAxis, 
    double angle) {
    ObservableList<Transform> transforms = node.getTransforms();
    try {
        for (Transform t : transforms) {
            rotationAxis = t.inverseDeltaTransform(rotationAxis);
           
        }
    } catch (NonInvertibleTransformException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    }
    
    transforms.add(new Rotate(angle, rotationAxis));
}
      
    
    

   public void start(Stage stage) {
 
      Box cube = new Box();  
     
       
    
      cam.getTransforms().addAll(rx, rz, ry);
     
      cube.setDepth(100.0);
      cube.setHeight(100.0);
      cube.setWidth(200.0);
      
      cube.setCullFace(CullFace.BACK);
    
      cube.setDrawMode(DrawMode.FILL);
      PhongMaterial material = new PhongMaterial();
      material.setDiffuseColor(Color.BROWN);
      cube.setMaterial(material);
    
      cube.setTranslateX(1500.0);
      cube.setTranslateY(500.0);
      cube.setTranslateZ(0.0);
    
      
      
      cam.setTranslateX(0);
      cam.setTranslateY(0);
      cam.setTranslateZ(0);
      cam.setScaleX(2);
      cam.setScaleY(2);
      cam.setScaleZ(2);

 
      Group root = new Group(cube, cam);
      Dimension dimension = 
      Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

      double screenHeight = dimension.getHeight();
      double screenWidth = dimension.getWidth();
       
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 0,0);
     
      stage.setFullScreen(true);
      scene.setCamera(cam);
      stage.setTitle("3d space");
      stage.setScene(scene);

     
      stage.show();
     


      stage.setOnHiding( event -> {  System.exit(0);} );
      //to get the input from a mouse vvvv  //
     ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = 
     Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
     Runnable toRun;
        toRun = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               
                if(!flip){
                    one = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
                    two = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
                    flip = true;
                }else{
                    flip = false;
                 
                    if(one > MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x){
                        
                        xt = xt +2;
               

                        ry.setAngle(xt);

        
                        System.out.println("left");
                    }else{
                        if(one < MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x){
                            System.out.println("right");
                            xt = xt -2;
                            ry.setAngle(xt);

                           
                            
                            
                            
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
ScheduledFuture<?> handle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(toRun, 1, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
 
   
 
 
    
   }
   public static void main(String args[]){
      launch(args);
   }
}
```

Comment: 1. Please fix the indentation in your code. It is really difficult to read like this. 2. You must not change the scene graph from the background thread. This is probably not the cause of your issue, but when you do this, no results are properly defined. 3. I don't know what you mean by "rotate around (0,0,0)". In 3 dimensional geometry there is no such thing as rotation around a point; only around an axis.

Comment: to be honest it just doesnt work but it looks like it revolving around a certain point

Comment: Again, "revolving around a point" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: it goes in a circle around a certain cords

Answer (score -2):

the answer is `cam.set.pivot(222)` to the area it circles around, also you can rotate everything around the camera